# how to remove view inside fragment

Tags: android, fragment

im new to android dev and fragments have been giving me a hard time.

Basically im making an app which requires the user to enter his time table (school) for 6 days a week.so ive made a fragment for each day (that is 6 fragments),also each of these fragments has an add subject button at the bottom which adds an xml layout when clicked. i have figured out how to add an edittext field and two buttons(one called data and the other called delete) , in the fragment using the layout from a xml file , now on clicking the delete button , i want that particular line to be deleted. how do i go about doing this ?

```
public class NewTimeTableMonday extends Fragment {

    Context context;            // context is needed to use inflater outside on create view
    View view;                  // view needs to be passed for (find view by id)
    private int unique_id = 0;  // for dynamic Id allocation when New Fields are created
    private final List<TextView> SUBJECT_NAME = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    public NewTimeTableMonday() {
                                // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_time_table_monday,
                container, false);
        context = container.getContext();

                                // adding two entries by default
        AddNewSubjectLine(view);
        AddNewSubjectLine(view);

        // for button +Add Another
        Button button_AddAnother = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.AddAnother);
        button_AddAnother.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddNewSubjectLine(view);
                                        // Adds another Subject Entry Line on the button being clicked
            }

        });

        // for button x

        Button button_crossDelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        button_crossDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DeleteSubjectLine(v);
                // Deletes that particular line when x is clicked
            }

        });

        // For Button Done
        Button button_Done = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Done);
        button_Done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // viewPager.setCurrentItem passes the arg0 value to getItem
                // to move to page 2 when done is clicked
                CreateNewTimetable.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }

        });

        return view;// because OnCreatView is of type View

    }
```

here is the addsubjectline function

```
public void AddNewSubjectLine(View view) {

        // To display another SUbject Entry Line
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View subjectLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_entry_line, null);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.MondayLayout);
        layout.addView(subjectLayout);

        /** Adding to list **/
        // Subject Name
        EditText subName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.SubName);
        subName.setId(unique_id);
        SUBJECT_NAME.add(subName);

        // Time Button
        Button button_EnterTime = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Time);
        button_EnterTime.setId(100 + unique_id);

        // Delete button
        Button deleteSub = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        deleteSub.setId(200 + unique_id);

        final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.scrollViewMonday);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }

        }, 400);

        unique_id++;

    }
```

and the two XML files used

this is fragment_new_time_table_monday.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewmonday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/monday"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutmonday"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddAnother"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Done"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/done" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMonday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewmonday"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutmonday"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MondayLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and xml new_line_entry

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/NewLineEntry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SubName"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/subjectname"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Time"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/time" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Delete"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/crossdelete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code and XML? It's easier then to propose solution.

Comment: actually could you show me a sample code on HOW to go about this particular project ? its a basic time table app , i wanted to include swip gestures when entering the time table.hence im using one fragment for each day. i want to dynamically add buttons in these fragments from an xml And dynamically delete them.

Comment: If you show some code and XML layouts I would be able to tell what to do next or if you should chose different approach. Also showing some screenshots would be helpful to understand what you did so far.

Comment: edited , just keep in mind that button X is put into the fragment by the addnewsubjectline function, so its on a different xml file

Comment: oh and please feel free to tell me anything that you find to be a bad programming practice.im just learning. ALso i cannot upload a screenshot because i do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: 3 questions: Are you using ViewPager to show these fragments? Are you creating separate XML layout file for each fragment? Is every day UI looking the same?

Comment: yes,viewpager is used to show the fragments.and yeah each day(fragment) has a separate xml file , and yes the UI is the same for every day.
which kinda makes the whole different xml files for different days redundant i know , do suggest a better alternative if possible

Answer (score 2):

if you want a view to not be shown, you can make it invisible, or gone.  You can also delete it from a view

### make it just not show

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view.setVIsibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

### really delete it

```
parent = view.getParent();
parent.removeView(view);
```

Comment: the thing is , im using two xml layouts , the View i used to inflate is from xml file 1 and then i add the xml file 2 (that is one edit text field and two bottons ) dynamically at the click of a button in xml file 1(if button is clicked twice , then another row of the same gets added).NOW i want to delete the entries made by xml file 2 (the edit text and two buttons) at the click of a button in xml file 2.

Comment: @Martin can you help me please. i am trying to show a fragment in relative layout on a button click. but its showing error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use single XML layout and Fragment implementation for one day. Just create separate instances of the Fragment for each day and let ViewPager to populate it.

I will not analyse entire code but I can definitely suggest to read [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) tutorials. There is also very good [video tutorial](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853) from Google on Udacity portal.

Regarding your code, as a quick solution, you can implement it like this:

**Set layout and subjectLayout final**

```
final View subjectLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_entry_line, null);
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view
        .findViewById(R.id.MondayLayout);
```

**Add click listener to delete button**

```
deleteSub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        layout.removeView(subjectLayout);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me....

deleteSub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    layout.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

});